# Set Starting index as 50001 in next dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 5 dataframes

Opening First one having 50000 rows

```
                Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN  
0     01-15-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R  
1     01-15-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R  
2     01-10-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R  
3     01-15-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R  
4     01-16-2021          AAACM6094R         AAACM6094R  
...          ...                 ...                ...  
49999   11-1-2023          AAACG4267G         AAACK1089Q
```

Opening Next Dataframe I need to set starting index as 50001 and smiliarily for the next dataframe
It should be 100001 And In last Dataframe it can be any number of rows but starting index should 200001

```
        vaex_df2.index = range(50001, vaex_df2.shape[0] + 1)
```

This throws error

```
      File "D:\test\CR6645script.py", line 361, in <module>
    CompareCSV(c,d)
  File "D:\test\CR6645script.py", line 84, in CompareCSV
    vaex_df2.index = range(50001, vaex_df2.shape[0] + 1)
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5491, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 763, in _set_axis
    self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 216, in set_axis        
    self._validate_set_axis(axis, new_labels)
  File "C:\Users\ncdex1124\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\base.py", line 57, in _validate_set_axis   
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1024 elements, new values have 0 elements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need add `50001` and remove  `+ 1`:

```
vaex_df2.index = range(50001, 50001 + vaex_df2.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
vaex_df2.index += 50001
vaex_df3.index += 100001
```

Or

```
vaex_df2.index += vaex_df1.index[-1] + 1
vaex_df3.index += vaex_df2.index[-1] + 1
```